# Is <tr> tag optional?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table>
  <td>cell1</td>
  <td>cell2</td>
</table>
```

I found out that this tags work on ie8, firefox 11 and chrome, but not sure whether this is valid by standards and work on all major browsers.

Comment: This might help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020429/do-optional-closing-html-tags-e-g-tr-present-extra-cost-to-browsers-html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All browsers accept "quirks" in HTML layout and will render a "best guess" based on what they find.  But in the HTML specifications, a `<tr>` tag is [DEFINITELY](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) required — regardless of whether it works or not, you should always use valid HTML!

Check early, check often!

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: +1 for the link! Later in that link (and perhaps more relevant) is http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3 which explicitly states "Each row group must contain at least one row, defined by the TR element." Given that all browsers render tables with a `<tbody>` elements (regardless if the source code has it or not), yes `<tr>` elements are required to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

`<tr>` tag is of course required with `<table>`, it specifies the begining and ending of the particular row, so it can't be neglected.

Comment: is there any reason to not using `<tr>` ?

Comment: since its required... no there is no reason