# Self-closing a <TD /> tag

Tags: html

I came across a code where a developer attempted to close an empty table cell like this `<TD />` instead of `<td></td>`.

Is `<td />` valid? When is it appropriate to close a tag like `<tag />`? What language does it come from originally?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (but doesn't address the direct question of 'is `<td />` a valid(void) tag'): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Non-HTML Compatible XHTML (so not if you want to use a `text/html` content-type or support IE 8 or older).

> If an element permits content (e.g., the div element) but an instance of that element has no content (e.g., an empty section), DO NOT use the "minimized" tag syntax (e.g., `<div />`).

— http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3

Answer (score -1):

No, `<td />` is not valid HTML. If you check this in the W3C's HTML validator, you get an error:

> Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of an error message about self-closing syntax being used on a non-void element]

However, in HTML, for table rows, you can declare opening table rows *without closing them* (see *[Is it safe to omit </TD> and </TR> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020374/is-it-safe-to-omit-td-and-tr-tags)* for more info); this is valid:

```
...
<tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum
    <td>Dolor Sit
</tr>
...
```

If I were to add an empty, self-closed td (e.g. `<td />` to that table row, it would *probably* be parsed by browsers like this:

```
...
<tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum
    <td>Dolor Sit
    <td>
</tr>
```

But this is not guaranteed, and it also may or may not be what you are wanting, so it is dangerous to rely on; you should only self-close valid void tags, a list of which can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element). For table elements, either use opening tags as shown above or use the much more common opening *and* closing tags, `<td>` and `</td>`, respectively.

Self-closing tags comes from XML/XHTML, as Quentin's answer already discusses.