# PHP Table Does Not Display All Data

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table which displays reviews written by users about products. The problem I am having is that the table isn't showing everything in the table. In other words, the data I want displayed is coming up but not the whole amount.

This is the code for my table:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE serial = '$id'")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo 'There Arent Any Reviews Yet';
    } else {

echo "<table width=100% border='6'><tr><th>Comments/Thoughts</th><th>Ratings</th><th>Date</th><th>User</th>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['review']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['ratings']. " Stars</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['date']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['user']. "</td>";
        }
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

when a user types in a review, only a few words in the table are shown. it seems like there is a limit to how much of the written review can be shown but i do not know where to change that value.

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE serial = '$id'")` - you aren't taking $id from the $_GET array, are you?

Comment: If you are indeed taking `$id` from `$_GET`, the code you show may be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: Please add more info about what kinds of rows are in the database, and are dropped. Also, are you 100% sure the data is not present in your HTML source code? How many rows should be displayed, and how many are displayed? What does `mysql_num_rows()` say?

Comment: Tip: You need to pass all user-supplied data that you output to the page through [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), otherwise users could insert HTML such as scripts or other malicious things, and cause havoc.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake from my own behalf...the table was set to varchar(45) <<< that was the limit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop needs to include `<tr>` tags (a.k.a table row tags) to correctly form the table. You also have a malformed table header.

```
echo "<table width=100% border='6'>
          <tr> 
              <th>Comments/Thoughts</th>
              <th>Ratings</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>User</th>
          </tr>"; // Missing TR here also!!
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['review']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['ratings']. " Stars</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['date']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['user']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: hi thank you for your reply, but it still does not fix my problem.

Comment: Did you fix both problems? (The `</tr>` inside the while loop AND the missing `</tr>` for the table heading?

Comment: The closing tags for `tr`, `th`, and `td` are completely optional in HTML. It will make no difference.

Comment: Indeed, @Boann is right! Heh, didn't know that. [Is it safe to omit </TD> and </TR> tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4020374)

Comment: sorry it was a mistake from my own behalf...the table was set to varchar(45) <<< that was the limit!

Comment: @Pekka - Only for HTML [4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224) - XHTML [requires it](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/#h-4.3).

Comment: @nickb: Obviously, but no-one actually uses XHTML because Internet Explorer has historically displayed it as a DOM tree. So servers serve it as `Content-Type: text/html`, and browsers have always parsed "XHTML" as classic tag soup. Nearly no-one has ever served actual XHTML to web browsers even if they think they have. Also, if that had been the problem here, the browser would have refused to display the page completely. Basically, anyone still caring about XHTML nowadays is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `</tr>` is in the wrong place:

```
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['review']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['ratings']. " Stars</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['date']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['user']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

It also looks like `$id` wasn't set anywhere in your code. Try putting this at the top of your code:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: hi thank you for your reply, but it still does not fix my problem.

Comment: Updated with a possible answer.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake from my own behalf...the table was set to varchar(45) <<< that was the limit!