# css, html - colspan not working the same on different tables

Tags: html, css

I have two html tables that I would like to align the same (the columns should be of equal width for the both tables). Both tables have a title that should span two columns at the start, and both should have four columns total.

What happens is even though the width of the columns is defined, the resize according to the column content.

```css
td,
th {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.red-header {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(184, 167, 177);
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" width="35%" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>
      <th width='35%' />
      <th width="15%" />
      <th width="15%" />
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="35%">something</td>
      <td width="35%">something else</td>
      <td width="15%">something</td>
      <td width="15%">something else</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" width="35%" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>
      <th width='35%' />
      <th width="15%">something</th>
      <th width="15%">something else</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody />
</table>
```

How do I make the columns retain their size regardless of the content?

Comment: Use `table-layout: fixed` and give it a width, e.g. `table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
`

Comment: ...and fix your table columns count, now you have 5 header cells and 4 content.

Comment: And note, table elements is not self closing tags `<th />`, they are start/end tags `<th></th>` ... you can omit the end one though (but is generally not recommended  as it is harder to read): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020374/is-it-safe-to-omit-td-and-tr-tags

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a1ve478c/

Comment: @LGSon thanks, that solved the issues I was having. You can write it up as an anwser and I'll accept it. Basically I needed `table-layout: fixed`, and also to remove the unnecesarry `td` elements where colspan was 2.

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič There is several answers for that already, so I closed it and linked to a few of them.

Answer (score -1):

You set the colspan to 2 in the second table yet you have the second header still there but missing the closing tag. if you remove the second heading missing the tag it should fix your problem.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" width="35%" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>
      <th width='35%' />
      <th width="15%" />
      <th width="15%" />
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="35%">something</td>
      <td width="35%">something else</td>
      <td width="15%">something</td>
      <td width="15%">something else</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" width="35%" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>

      <th width="15%">something</th>
      <th width="15%">something else</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody />
</table>
```

or close the tag

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" width="35%" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>
      <th width='35%' />
      <th width="15%" />
      <th width="15%" />
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="35%">something</td>
      <td width="35%">something else</td>
      <td width="15%">something</td>
      <td width="15%">something else</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" width="35%" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>
      <th width='35%' /></th>
      <th width="15%">something</th>
      <th width="15%">something else</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody />
</table>
```

Comment: Nope, that does not fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand what you are asking. I will look again.

Comment: Missing close tag is not the issue ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020374/is-it-safe-to-omit-td-and-tr-tags

Comment: Why are you setting the colspan to 2? It does not add up.

Comment: I am not the one who asked ... but the main issue here is not about that (event if it has an issue with unequal cols), it is how to ensure that the table cells keeps their size no matter content.

Answer (score -1):

the one mistake i found your code is that you are missing closing for th tag in multiple places ..you can either use colspan or percentage of the width using both at same time dont make sense you can do this way using colspan

```css
table{
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >something</td>
      <td >something else</td>
      <td >something</td>
      <td >something else</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" width="35%" class="red-header">
        THIS IS A LONG LONG HEADER STRING
      </th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >something</td>
      <td >something else</td>
      <td >something</td>
      <td >something else</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nope, not the issue ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020374/is-it-safe-to-omit-td-and-tr-tags